# How to create 1 order to allow multiple choices of 1 product with varied quantity?

Tags: configurable-product, order-grid

I have a requirement where -- I would like people to be able to order 1 product + its multiple variations in varied quantity. This can be termed as Bulk Order or Grouped Order -- but below is a table what I am looking forward to use.

[image]

User should be able to fill in the [quantity] field & then add to cart.

Any thoughts (or any Addons) would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple in Magento because Magento provide us the to create the Bundle product.

SO for the refer the  [creating a bundled product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product)

For Example

1. Create a **bundled product** named "*Auto Floor Mats Set*".
2. Create **4 configurable products** named :

   - "*Front-Left Mat*"
   - "*Front-Right Mat*"
   - "*Back-Left Mat*"
   - "*Back-Right Mat*"

   then
3. Create **3 simple products** for each configurable product and associate them with configurable products created in previous step ( e.g. create simple products named :

   - "*Red Front-Left Mat*"
   - "*Green Front-Left Mat*"
   - "*Blue Front-Left Mat*"

   and associate them with configurable product "*Front-Left Mat*")
4. In your bundled product, go to "*Bundle items" -> "Add New Option*" and **create 4 options** :

   - "*Front-Left*"
   - "*Front-Right*"
   - "*Back-Left*"
   - "*Back-Right*"

   and **add 3 selections** for each option. e.g. add simple products :

   - "*Red Front-Left Mat*"
   - "*Green Front-Left Mat*"
   - "*Blue Front-Left Mat*"

   as selections for option "*Front-Left Mat*".

That's all !

Comment: Thanks for the quick heads-up. Let me try here & get back with any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @keyul-shah, that was helpful.

I also found Magento KB on [Configurable Product](https://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product) useful for similar need. Adding here in case someone reaches here for the same.

Comment: ok Tush I will also look into that